# Why does a simple user password allow root access on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, sudo

I have a client who I setup with a linux machine.  He isn't very tech savvy, and obviously just needed a simple password to log onto ubuntu with.  His username and password are something like:

```
user: John
password: GoodDeals
```

On the other hand, the root password on the machine is much more complex, and is something only I should have access to.

But when I use the command:

```
sudo su -
```

Ubuntu prompts for John's simple password and then grants root access to the entire machine.

This could be an issue, as once an employee knew the simple password to log onto the machine, they could essentially gain root access with it.

Is this intended behavior?

Why does knowing a user account password automatically give you root access?

Comment: You can configure which users/groups can use sudo and what coomands they can run with sudo.

Comment: Should root be in sudo group?  I realized I need to remove John from sudo, but root isn't in there.  Should it be?

Comment: No. The default `/etc/sudoer` has a line for `root`.

Comment: Obligatory https://xkcd.com/1200/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out John was in sudo group when he shouldn't be.  Removed John from sudo using this command:

```
gpasswd -d john sudo
```

And this resolved the issue.  If he tries to escalate privileges now he is unable to.

Comment: Something worth remembering is ubuntu *automatically* assumes the first user you add (during install) is the admin. I personally just set up my default admin account, then add any un(der) privileged accounts as needed later.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the Ubuntu distribution of Linux comes with root login disabled and root password unset, so to raise his privilege level a user needs to run commands with `sudo`, and that is permitted only when user is a sudoer (having its entry in the `sudoers` file) which is as following for brief:

**Members of the admin group may gain root privileges**

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

**Allow members of group sudo to execute any command**

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

**Root and users in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user**

```
root            ALL = (ALL) ALL
%wheel          ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

**Full time sysadmins can run anything on any machine without a password**

```
FULLTIMERS      ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**Part time sysadmins may run anything but need a password**

```
PARTTIMERS      ALL = ALL
```

---

And the command that you are running is

```
sudo /sbin/su -
```

which, when run by `sudo` user, will not prompt for password (sudo password not root password) if RootSudoTimeout didn't occur, to Restrict this

**john may `su` only to operator**

```
john        ALL = /usr/bin/su operator
```

**john may `su` to anyone but root and flags are not allowed**

```
john        ALPHA = /usr/bin/su [!-]*, !/usr/bin/su *root*
```

Answer (score 2):

Knowing a user account password doesn't give root access automatically.
**Sudo** is intended for root access for priviledged users like your John, using user's password in contrary to **su**, that need root's password to execute any command.
Show the output of **id** command for John. I suppose you've set your Ubuntu up with this username, so that John is in sudo group by default.

Comment: "John is in sudo group by default."  -- good to know how that happened.